# javascript ReferenceError on onclick

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script>
              function view_more(pg_no){
               alert(pg_no);
              }
       </script>
   </head>
  <body>
    <span onClick="view_more('1')"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here, I can't understand why it say always
[ReferenceError: view_more is not defined]

Comment: Not sure either http://jsfiddle.net/GDQta/

Comment: When do you get that error? Are there any other javascript errors on the page? Please make sure you have thoroughly debugged your code before posting a question.

Comment: you should check your console, code is fine

Comment: WHAT IS THE BROWSER YOU ARE USING! :P

Comment: this code is working perfect for me, on both Firefox and chrome. :) just add any text in the span.

Comment: You are not telling us the whole story here

Comment: Maybe he's doing this and that's why it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/GDQta/1/

Comment: Doing what? Setting the jsFiddle to mootools and not adding the script in the head?

Comment: No matter what framework he sets.

Comment: In this case it works: http://jsfiddle.net/GDQta/2/

Comment: ok i got the error thanks for your help

Comment: I know this question is pretty old, but for anyone getting here with a similar problem like me > Changing jsfiddle default "onLoad" to "No wrap" using no library (pure JS)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today.
My situation was like this:

.html file:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="lc-form-holder">
        <form action="#" method="post">
        [...]
            <span onclick="myFunction();">NEXT</span>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

and .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function myFunction() {
        console.log('click click');
    }
});
```

When I clicked on `<span>` I got an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFuncion is not defined`.

But when I do this in .js file (no `document.ready`):

```
    function myFunction() {
        console.log('click click');
    }
```

Everything work just fine.

I don't know is this helpful but I wanna share it if someone check this question in future.

Answer (score -1):

```
<span onClick="view_more('1')">Test</span>
```

Add text and then click on text

Working at my end

This is my code --

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script>
              function view_more(pg_no){
               alert(pg_no);
              }
       </script>
   </head>
  <body>
    <span onClick="view_more('1')">gfgf</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

try using this code --

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function view_more(pg_no)
{
alert(pg_no);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span onClick="javascript:view_more('1');">gfgf</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really dont know why downvoted check fiddle as it working for me as well http://jsfiddle.net/GDQta/ what Ray mentioned

Comment: Pseudo label `javascript:` is ONLY needed if the first script on the page is VBScript and the browser is IE

Answer (score -1):

Try this first

```
<body>
<span onClick="alert('1');"></span>
```

if the above code works then there must exists others javascript which are actually got error prior to execute your code.